# Evitar doble consulta para imprimir reporte de crystal report c#

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, crystal-reports

quiero plantear la siguiente duda no se si estoy en lo correcto.

1. genero una view en la que recibe parámetros para poder generar un reporte y cargarlo como partialview el código es el siguiente.

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public ActionResult ResumenProcedimientos(SearchProcedimiento model)
   {

       #region ResumenProcedimientos

       var list = from t in db.MtoProcedimientos
                  where model.itemLicitaciones.Contains(t.MtoProcedimientoId) ||
                        model.itemTipoEventos.Contains(t.MtoTipoEventoId)
                  select t;

       return View("_ResumenProcedimientos", list);

       #endregion
   }
   ```

esto me genera la información solicitada y me muestra la partialview con el filtro realizado, como muestro en la siguiente imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

bien ahora quisiera que al imprimir el botón de imprimir me mostrara un reporte en crystal report pero evitando enviar los parametros de consulta al metodo de imprimir, existe alguna forma?.

lo que quiero es evitar volver a consultar la base de datos para poder generar el reporte

el actionresult para poder imprimir es el siguiente.

```
 public ActionResult ExportPDF(int? MtoProcedimientoId, int? MtoProveedorId)
    {
        #region ExportPDF
        var reporte = this.GenerateReport(MtoProcedimientoId, MtoProveedorId, false);
        var stream = reporte.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);

        return File(stream, "application/pdf");
        #endregion
    }
```

y este método es el que genera el reporte

```
   private ReportClass GenerateReport(int? MtoProcedimientoId, int? MtoProveedorId, bool Excel)
        {
            #region GenerateReport
            var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
            var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            var datatable = new DataTable();

            var sql = @"SELECT A.MtoOfertaId, E.DetalleOfertaId, D.Ejercicio, D.NoLicitacion, C.RazonSocial, C.RfcProveedor, F.Descripcion AS Estratificacion,             A.MtoProcedimientoId, A.MtoProveedorId, 
                      B.Partida, A.Gpo + ' ' + A.Gen + ' ' + A.Esp + ' ' + A.Dif + ' ' + A.[Var] AS Clave, B.Descripcion, B.Pmr, A.PrecioOfertado, A.Descuento,
                    A.PrecioNeto, A.MaximoOfertado, 
                  A.MinimoOfertado, A.MontoPartida, E.Marca, E.RegistroSanitario, E.TitularRegistro, E.RfcTitular, E.Origen, E.Fabricante, E.RfcFabricante
FROM     dbo.MtoOferta AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.MtoRequerimiento AS B ON A.MtoRequerimientoId = B.MtoRequerimientoId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.MtoProveedor AS C ON A.MtoProveedorId = C.MtoProveedorId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.MtoProcedimiento AS D ON B.MtoProcedimientoId = D.MtoProcedimientoId AND A.MtoProcedimientoId = D.MtoProcedimientoId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.DetalleOferta AS E ON A.MtoOfertaId = E.MtoOfertaId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.MtoEstratificacion AS F ON C.MtoEstratificacionId = F.MtoEstratificacionId
GROUP BY A.MtoOfertaId, E.DetalleOfertaId, D.Ejercicio, D.NoLicitacion, C.RazonSocial, C.RfcProveedor, F.Descripcion, A.MtoProcedimientoId, A.MtoProveedorId, B.Partida, 
                  A.Gpo + ' ' + A.Gen + ' ' + A.Esp + ' ' + A.Dif + ' ' + A.[Var], B.Descripcion, B.Pmr, A.PrecioOfertado, A.Descuento, A.PrecioNeto, A.MaximoOfertado, A.MinimoOfertado, 
                  A.MontoPartida, E.Marca, E.RegistroSanitario, E.TitularRegistro, E.RfcTitular, E.Origen, E.Fabricante, E.RfcFabricante
HAVING A.MtoProcedimientoId = " + MtoProcedimientoId;

            if (MtoProveedorId != 0)
            {
                sql = sql + " and  a.MtoProveedorId=" + MtoProveedorId;
            }

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                adapter.Fill(datatable);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                ex.ToString();
            }

            string DirectorioReportesRelativo = "~/Reportes/Apertura/";


            var report = new ReportClass();
            if (Excel)
            {
                //report.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/Reportes/Apertura/ValOfertasDetalle.rpt");
                string urlArchivo = string.Format("{0}.{1}", "ValOfertasDetalle", "rpt");

                string FullPathReport = string.Format("{0}{1}",
                                        this.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(DirectorioReportesRelativo),
                                         urlArchivo);

                report.FileName = FullPathReport;
            }
            else
            {
                string urlArchivo = string.Format("{0}.{1}", "ValidaOfertas", "rpt");

                string FullPathReport = string.Format("{0}{1}",
                                        this.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(DirectorioReportesRelativo),
                                         urlArchivo);

                report.FileName = FullPathReport;
            }
            report.Load();

            report.SetDataSource(datatable);

            return report;
            #endregion

        }
```

quiero evitar la consulta sql a la base de datos.

muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Ciertamente podrías, siempre y cuando :

- El crystal reports acepte un lista de objetos(para el body de tu reporte, parámetros para tu header o valores que no se repitan), echa un ojo [aquí](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/50657/assign-List-object-to-a-dataset-in-crystal-reports) , solo que aquí usan un data table; igual  depende de la versión de crystal que estés empleando
- Debes guardar el resultado de la primera consulta en sesión para después pasárselo a crystal

Answer (score 0):

que tal gracias amigo iker muchas gracias les comento como quedo al final, en el metodo de busqueda hice las siguientes modificaciones.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ResumenProcedimientos(SearchProcedimiento model)
    {

        #region ResumenProcedimientos
        DataTable objDataTable = new DataTable("tblSongs");

        objDataTable.Columns.Add("EJercicio");
        objDataTable.Columns.Add("NoLicitacion");
        objDataTable.Columns.Add("Descripcion");
        objDataTable.Columns.Add("TipoProcedimiento");
        objDataTable.Columns.Add("ClavesRequeridas");
        objDataTable.Columns.Add("PiezasRequeridas");
        objDataTable.Columns.Add("MontoRequerido");
        objDataTable.Columns.Add("ClavesAsignadas");
        objDataTable.Columns.Add("PiezasAsignadas");
        objDataTable.Columns.Add("MontoAsignado");            
        DataRow myDataRow;


        var list = from t in db.MtoProcedimientos
                   where model.itemLicitaciones.Contains(t.MtoProcedimientoId) ||
                         model.itemTipoEventos.Contains(t.MtoTipoEventoId)
                   select t;

        foreach (var items in list)
        {
            myDataRow = objDataTable.NewRow();
            myDataRow[0] = items.Ejercicio;
            myDataRow[1] = items.NoLicitacion;
            myDataRow[2] = items.Descripcion;
            myDataRow[3] = items.MtoTipoEvento.DescripcionCorta;                
            myDataRow[4] = items.ClavesReq;
            myDataRow[5] = items.PiezasReq;
            myDataRow[6] = items.MontoReq;
            myDataRow[7] = 0;
            myDataRow[8] = 0;
            myDataRow[9] = 0;

            objDataTable.Rows.Add(myDataRow);
        }

        Session["ResumenProcedimientos"] = objDataTable;




        return View("_ResumenProcedimientos", list);

        #endregion
    }
```

ahora en el metodo para imprimir el reporte

```
public ActionResult ExportarResumen() 
    {

        if (Session["ResumenProcedimientos"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["ResumenProcedimientos"];//Session["ResumenProcedimientos"] as DataTable;


            var reporte = this.GenerateReportResumen(dt);
            var stream = reporte.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
            return File(stream, "application/pdf");
        }

        return View();
    }
```

y el actionresult que crea el reporte quedo asi.

```
private ReportClass GenerateReportResumen(DataTable table)
    {
        #region GenerateReport


        string DirectorioReportesRelativo = "~/Reportes/Procedimientos/";


        var report = new ReportClass();
        {

            //string urlArchivo = string.Format("{0}.{1}", "ResumenMontobyProcedimientos", "rpt");
            string urlArchivo = string.Format("{0}.{1}", "ResumenByLic", "rpt");

            string FullPathReport = string.Format("{0}{1}",
                                    this.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(DirectorioReportesRelativo),
                                     urlArchivo);

            report.FileName = FullPathReport;
        }

        report.Load();

        report.SetDataSource(table);

        return report;
        #endregion

    }
```

el boton en la view quedo asi.

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Imprimir", "ExportarResumen", null, new { @class = "fa  fa-file-pdf-o",  target = "_blank" })
```